# ExpressJS handlebars template does not display data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have an expressJS project where there's a page where i need to display data after i fetch from AJAX request. I am using .hbs files for the view.

I have tried different methods for this to work. It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ezjvagym/).

For simplicity i am using basic data.

```
<div id="content">

</div>
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div name="entry">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <div class="body">
      {{body}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var source = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source)
        var context = { title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!" }
        var html = template(context)

        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html
        console.log(html)

    })();
</script>
```

I expect the context data to be displayed in the template. Currently the template prints no data. `console.log(html)` prints html without data

Comment: Is there any reason you're rendering you're template client-side instead of doing it server-side?

Comment: I want to make AJAX request and render the data in the template. The above snippet is just for simplicity.

Comment: it works in my browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have found the solution. I now know what i was doing wrong.